# Media Sharing not turning on

Tags: macos, home-sharing

I cant start Home Sharing because I cant get Media Sharing to turn on. I was about to start Home Sharing to my Apple TV. Please help.

macOS Monterey 12.6.2
[image]

Comment: Have you signed in with an AppleId to iTunes?

Comment: Yes I did it already @mmmmmm

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an edit link below it) to add info such as what you've already tried (so we're not suggesting things you've already done), whether this is a new issue (e.g. it used to work, but now doesn't). If it did work previously, has anything changed (e.g. new hardware, just upgraded to macOS Monterey, etc).